# passing corresponding text-field values into the function which has the same id's

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button called "Add text field". When it is clicked, the group of HTML elements like two text-fields-"Text input", "file name" and one button -"Download audio file", would be created. When a "Download audio file" button is clicked, it should take the input from the corresponding text fields like "Text input" and "file name" to be passed into the function start().

Important thing is these text fields are added into the DOM with innerHTML so all the iteration would have the same id for the text-fields and even for button.

My HTML:

```
<form class="col-sm-12">
<div id="textfields">

                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="Textarea1">Text Input</label>
                                        <!--
                                        <textarea class="form-control" id="textarea1" rows="10"></textarea>-->
                                        <textarea class='form-control' id='textarea'"+textareaid=1+" rows='10'></textarea>
                                </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-3 ml-auto">
                                <div class="form-row">
                                        <label for="Textarea2">File Name</label>      
                                        <!--                                  
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="filename">-->
                                        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='filename'"+filenameid=1+">
                                </div></br>
                                <div class="form-row text-center">
                                        <div class="col-12">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="start();">Download audio file</button>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addTextFields();">Add Text field</button>

    </form>
```

JavaScript to add text-fields:

```
var textareaid=2; var filenameid=2;
        function addTextFields(){
            var objTo = document.getElementById('textfields');
            var divtest = document.createElement("div");
            divtest.innerHTML = "<div class='form-row'><div class='col-sm-8'><div class='form-group'><label for='Textarea1'>Text Input</label><textarea class='form-control' id='textarea'"+textareaid+" rows='10'></textarea></div></div><div class='col-sm-3 ml-auto'><div class='form-group'><label for='Textarea2'>File Name</label><input type='text' class='form-control' id='filename'"+filenameid+"></br><div class='form-row text-center'><div class='col-12'><button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' onclick='start();'>Download audio file</button></div></div></div></div></div>";
            objTo.appendChild(divtest);     
               textareaid++;
               filenameid++;
        }
```

API request for start():

```
'body': {
                            "input": {
                                 "text":document.getElementById("textarea"+textareaid).value,
                            "filename":document.getElementById("filename"+filenameid).value
                            },
                            "voice": {
                                "languageCode": document.getElementById("languages").value,
                                "ssmlGender": document.getElementById("gender").value,
                                "name": document.getElementById("entries").value
                            }                               
                        }
```

Problem is, when the button is clicked from the second group of elements, it is still taking the parameters from first iteration instead of the second one.

This is how the elements look like in [HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EqgB.jpg).

Any ideas would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Since Id's should not be same use class if you want to control multiple controls with same name. You can assign different ids to each textarea by replacing script with this so that every time new id will generate for every textarea hence it will unique.

```
  <script>
var textareaid=2;
function addTextFields(){
            var objTo = document.getElementById('textfields');
            var divtest = document.createElement("div");
            divtest.innerHTML = "<div class='form-row'><div class='col-sm-8'><div class='form-group'><label for='Textarea1'>Text Input</label><textarea class='form-control' id='textarea"+textareaid+"'"+              
            "rows='10'></textarea></div></div><div class='col-sm-3 ml-auto'><div class='form-group'><label for='Textarea2'>File Name</label><input type='text' class='form-control' id='textarea"+textareaid+"></br><div class='form-row text-center'><div class='col-12'><button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' onclick='start();'>Download audio file</button></div></div></div></div></div>";
            objTo.appendChild(divtest);     
               textareaid++;

        }  

</script>
```

Comment: I have edited my code with your idea. I am getting some error. How should I pass this id as a variable in HTML? Edited all my HTML, JS, API request too. Am getting: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'error' of undefined`

Comment: I don't know how to pass the variables in from the HTML ID. Even, if I did by the above method, I couldn't get the right output.

Comment: I am not able to understand from where you want to pass ID.please tell more clear

Comment: I am passing the ID from HTML to API request for start(). But, I couldn't do that.

Comment: that is not API request which you have shown in your code that could be the response

Comment: I have written only a few lines of 'body' from API POST request over there. It was working before. I couldn't post the entire thing.

Comment: Now even the first iteration is not working which would work before. I am using, id='textarea'+textareaid and id='filename'+filenameid in the HTML.